Using WeatherKit SunEvents
I am attempting to use weatherKit to get the sunrise and sunset so that I can change the WeatherConditionIcons depending upon if the time is before or after sunrise and sunset. Originally I was just getting day time icons but not I am only receiving night time icons. I used a debugging line to get the sunrise and sunset time to print. However, the sunrise and sunset time are printing that they are happening 4 hours after the actual sunrise and sunset. Here is the code I have right now:
@MainActor
class WeatherData: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = WeatherData()
    let service = WeatherService.shared
    @Published var currentWeather: CurrentWeather?
    @Published var hourlyForecast: [HourWeather] = []
    @Published var dailyForecast: [DayWeather] = []

    @Published var cityName: String = ""

    @Published var sunEvents: SunEvents?

    func updateWeather(for location: CLLocation) {
        Task {
             do {
                 let currentForecast = try await service.weather(for: location, including: .current)
            await MainActor.run {
                self.currentWeather = currentForecast
            }

            let dailyForecast = try await service.weather(for: location, including: .daily)
            await MainActor.run {
                self.dailyForecast = dailyForecast.forecast
                if let firstDayWeather = dailyForecast.forecast.first {
                    self.sunEvents = firstDayWeather.sun
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch weather data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
}

struct HourlyForecastView: View {
@ObservedObject var weatherData: WeatherData

var body: some View {
   VStack {
       if let startDate = weatherData.hourlyForecast.first?.date, let endDate = weatherData.hourlyForecast.last?.date {
           HStack {
               Text("\(formatDate(startDate)) to \(formatDate(endDate))")
                   .font(.caption)
           }
           .padding([.leading, .trailing])
       }
       ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
           HStack(spacing: 20) {
               ForEach(weatherData.hourlyForecast, id: \.date) { hourWeather in
                   VStack(spacing: 5) {
                       Text(hourWeatherFormatter.string(from: hourWeather.date))
                           .font(.caption)
                       
                       Image(systemName: weatherData.getWeatherConditionIcon(for: hourWeather.condition, at: hourWeather.date))
                           .foregroundColor(.blue)
                       
                       Text("\(hourWeather.precipitationChance * 100, specifier: "%.0f%%")")
                           .font(.caption)
                           .foregroundColor(.blue)
                       
                       Text("\(hourWeather.temperature.value, specifier: "%.1f°")")
                           .font(.caption)
                   }
                   .frame(width: 40, height: 105)
               }
           }
           .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7).fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2)))
       }
   }
}

private var hourWeatherFormatter: DateFormatter {
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "ha"
   formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
   formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
   return formatter
}

 private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return formatter.string(from: date)
 }
}

extension WeatherData {
func getWeatherConditionIcon(for condition: WeatherCondition, at time: Date) -> String {
      guard let sunEvents = dailyForecast.first?.sun else {
          print("No SunEvents data available, defaulting to daytime icons.")
          return getDefaultIcon(for: condition, isDaytime: true)
      }

      print("Sunrise: \(String(describing: sunEvents.sunrise)), Sunset: \(String(describing: sunEvents.sunset)), Current Time: \(time)")

      let isDaytime: Bool
      if let sunrise = sunEvents.sunrise, let sunset = sunEvents.sunset {
          isDaytime = time >= sunrise && time <= sunset
      } else {
          isDaytime = true
      }

      return getDefaultIcon(for: condition, isDaytime: isDaytime)
  }

private func getDefaultIcon(for condition: WeatherCondition, isDaytime: Bool) -> String {
    switch condition {
    case .clear:
        return isDaytime ? "sun.max.fill" : "moon.stars.fill"
    case .cloudy:
        return "cloud.fill"
    case .drizzle, .rain:
        return isDaytime ? "cloud.drizzle.fill" : "cloud.drizzle.fill.bolt"
    case .snow:
        return "snow"
    case .sleet:
        return "cloud.sleet.fill"
    case .hail:
        return "cloud.hail.fill"
    case .thunderstorms, .scatteredThunderstorms, .strongStorms:
        return "cloud.bolt.rain.fill"
    case .foggy:
        return "cloud.fog.fill"
    case .partlyCloudy:
        return isDaytime ? "cloud.sun.fill" : "cloud.moon.fill"
    case .mostlyCloudy:
        return "cloud.fill"
    case .mostlyClear:
        return isDaytime ? "sun.max.fill" : "moon.stars.fill"
    case .windy, .breezy:
        return "wind"
    case .smoky:
        return "smoke.fill"
    case .haze:
        return isDaytime ? "sun.haze.fill" : "moon.haze.fill"
    case .blowingDust:
        return "sun.dust.fill"
    case .heavyRain:
        return "cloud.heavyrain.fill"
    case .sunShowers:
        return isDaytime ? "sun.rain.fill" : "moon.rain.fill"
    case .isolatedThunderstorms:
        return "cloud.bolt.rain.fill"
    case .tropicalStorm, .hurricane:
        return "hurricane"
    case .blizzard, .blowingSnow, .heavySnow:
        return "snowflake"
    case .frigid:
        return "thermometer.snowflake"
    case .hot:
        return "thermostat.sun"
    case .wintryMix:
        return "cloud.snow.fill"
    default:
        return "questionmark.circle.fill"
    }
}
}

